# Welche Grammatik wurde hier benutzt?

Tags: grammar-identification

Heute in den Nachrichten habe ich gehört:

> Der Mann steht im Verdacht, wahllos auf die Parade zum US-Unabhängigkeitstag gefeuert zu haben.

Was ist die Grammatik für den Teil *steht im Verdacht ... gefeuert zu haben* (insbesondere der Teil *gefeuert zu haben*)? Ich konnte dazu nichts finden und es auch nicht genau erklären. Die Bedeutung ist mir generell eigentlich klar, es ist ähnlich wie *er soll auf ... gefeuert haben*, aber ich konnte dazu nichts Genaueres finden.

Answer (score 2):

Das ist eine [nebensatzwertige Infinitivphrase](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitiv#Nebensatzwertige_Infinitivphrasen) (hier in der Ausprägung Perfekt/Aktiv), auch *erweiterter Infinitiv* genannt; der Nebensatz beschreibt den *Verdacht* näher; für manche Sachverhalte gibt es dafür ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv wie *Mordverdacht*.

Comment: Top, danke! Welche genaue Form ist "gefeuert zu haben" denn? Sieht für mich nach Perfekt Aktiv aus, aber sicher bin ich mir bei der Grammatik schon lange nicht.

Comment: Gute Antwort aber im Grunde als Link  nicht mehr als einen Kommentar wert.